# .? (existence) operator in ruby?

Tags: ruby, null

Is there a `.?` operator in Ruby that checks if an object is `nil` before calling a method on it?

For instance if I have to code:

```
if person and person.neighbor and person.neighbor.house and person.neighbor.house.rooms
    person.neighbor.house.rooms.each do |room|
        blah
    end
end
```

Is there a better way than having to do an if check on everything?

And please don't say "code in such a way that these objects cannot ever be `nil`", I am getting these things from an API call and can't control it.

Comment: The [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) may be interesting to you, as your code violates it heavily.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an equivalent null prevention on chained attributes of groovy in ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8805582/is-there-an-equivalent-null-prevention-on-chained-attributes-of-groovy-in-ruby)

Comment: @AndrewMarshal, I definitely agree. However I can't think of a good way to follow LoD in my case. I am basically making an API call to a 3rd party authentication platform (ie facebook twitter etc) and getting back a huge nested object of information. Within this, I only want to grab 1 piece of info (specifically, the user's education history), which is deeply nested. Unless I write 5 different methods each of which only makes a call to its descendent, I am forced to violate LoD. Maybe there's a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest thing to do is use the [andand](http://andand.rubyforge.org/) gem, although there are some other, pretty trivially-implemented options, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721949/simplify-multiple-nil-checking-in-rails/8722096#8722096), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8805582/is-there-an-equivalent-null-prevention-on-chained-attributes-of-groovy-in-ruby/8805969#8805969), or etc.

Answer (score 6):

As of Ruby 2.3.0, the `&.` "safe navigation" operator does exactly this. So instead of

`person and person.neighbor and person.neighbor.house and person.neighbor.house.rooms`

you can now just do

`person&.neighbor&.house&.rooms`.

http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/

Answer (score 1):

The method you are looking for is `nil?`

Example:

```
foo.nil?
```

For a more elegant approaches to programming defensive against `nil` values, see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9349668/745359) on the same topic. For example you could write:

```
person.neighbor.house.rooms.each do |room|
    blah
end
rescue false
```

Comment: You don't want to rescue arbitrary exceptions, though.

Comment: @DaveNewton: If theres something like a nil exception please feel free to edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

For second case, checking for does the object have a list of methods or not, you may use [try](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try) method

```
require "active_support/core_ext/object/try"
person.try(:neighbor).try(:house).try(:rooms).each do |room|
   blah
end
```

Or my version of `try`

```
class Object
  def try(*args, &block)
    if args.empty? and block_given?
      begin
        instance_eval &block
      rescue NameError => e
        puts e.message + ' ' + e.backtrace.first
      end
    elsif respond_to?(args.first)
      send(*args, &block)
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can do it in short way:

```
person.try{neighbor.house.rooms}.each do |room|
   blah
end
```

Answer (score 1):

why not

```
begin
    person.neighbor.house.rooms.each do |room|
        ...
    end
rescue NameError
    ...
end
```

Exception handlers are made for handle exception :) So if you depend on someone else code, you should not prevent but handle your code for crash, not to check if everything is ok.